# zenfone 5 lollipop update fails

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, asus-zenfone-5

I'm using Zenfone 5 with firmware ww_user_2.22.40.53. When I try to upgarde with 3.23.40.52, it fails,saying only android 4.2.2 and 5.0 can update with this package. What should I do?

Comment: Firelord: Kitkat 4.4.2 is my OS. I've tried to upgrade by adb sideload and by copying the upgrade file to internal memory and by clicking on the notification. Both lead me to the above error

Comment: Can you link the tutorial that you followed, or from where you downloaded the firmware?

Comment: http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=11408 this is the tutorial, but their lollipop link is broken. So i downloaded it from official website

Comment: I have downgraded my phone from 2.22.40.54 to 53 when i read that its the bridge firmware

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Downgrade the firmware to 2.22.40.53 then upgrade back to 54. Now your root is long gone. Then 54 will detect the lollipop firmware. Upgrade it and wipe cache from recovery mode. =)